# OpenLayers Vector Layer z-ordering on feature labels

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

**EDIT:** I have filed a bug ticket for this on GitHub: https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/issues/1167

I'm working on a project with OpenLayers and have found the experience quite painful due to the lack of good documentation. I've followed the example here http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/ordering.html to create icons on the map with z-ordering. However, I am also using a variation of the technique here http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features-with-text.html to create labels for the vectors. Unfortunaely, it seems like OpenLayers does not respect z-ordering properties when it draws labels.

[image: OpenLayers incorrect z-ordering]

Notice how the green icon is on top of the grey icon (correct), but the green label is below the grey label (incorrect.) Is there a workaround for this?

Here's my code for the layer:

```
    this.vehicleLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vehicles", {
        // The zIndex is taken from the zIndex attribute of the features
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 'default': {
            graphicZIndex: "${zIndex}"
        }}),
        // enable the indexer by setting zIndexing to true
        rendererOptions: {zIndexing: true}
    });
```

Here's my code for the icons:

```
    iconPrefix = mapView.iconProvider.prefixMapping(vehicle.get('icon'));
    imgUrl = mapView.iconProvider.getIconURL(iconPrefix, trackingStatus, position.get('track'));

    //Vehicle icon
    this.marker = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, {
        'graphicZIndex': this.zIndexState[trackingStatus],
        'externalGraphic': imgUrl,
        'pointRadius': 8,
        'cursor': 'pointer',
        'clickable': true,
        'title': label_text
    });

    this.marker.attributes = {
        'vehicleMapView': this
    };

    //tail label
    if (App.Settings.get('labels')) {
        this.marker.style = _.extend(this.marker.style, {
            pointerEvents: "visiblePainted",
            label: label_text,
            fontColor: trackingStatus !== 'inactive' ? "#222222" : "white",
            fontSize: "12px",
            fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            labelAlign: "lm",
            labelXOffset:12,
            labelOutlineColor: this.statusToColor[trackingStatus],
            labelOutlineWidth: 2.5
        });
        this.marker.attributes = _.extend(this.marker.attributes, {label: label_text});

    }
    layer.addFeatures([this.marker]);
```

Comment: I have not had a problem with z-ordering the labels. please provide `code`. Probably just something wrong with your "variation of a technique".

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I've updated the post with my code.

Comment: Looks like this was also asked... in 2011. And no answer. :( http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2011-March/020097.html

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try if you haven't already:

I noticed you enabled `rendererOptions` on your first vector but not your second. You could try adding that to your second layer too.

Also try removing the quotes from `"${zIndex}"` to simply `${zIndex}` since it probably expects an integer.

Comment: Thanks, but all of this code is in the same Layer. Also, my code isn't using the `styleMap` `graphicZIndex` mapper since I'm setting the `graphicZIndex` directly in each `Vector` Feature. 

I think this is just a bug in OpenLayers because they use the SVG renderer to draw the labels, which doesn't support z-indexing. The ticket for this bug has this in a "TODO" list, but the bug is marked as resolved, so I have no idea if it'll ever be supported.

Comment: I'm bubbling up features to the top based on which feature is closest to the mouse.. It's working well with styleMap and some style rules to hilight the one I note as 'selected' as well as a custom mousemove event.

It seems like the easiest and most direct method of circumventing this problem is to use a layer on top of the vector layer and empty it and add in the floating feature.

If you're simply looking to reorder.. you'll have to recreate all the vectors in order :|

Answer (score 0):

The possible workaround is to change the text container to graphic container and it will obey the z-index on rendering text:

```
layer.renderer.textRoot = layer.renderer.vectorRoot;
```